# Gremlin - How do find vertices with 'null' property?

Tags: gremlin

Let's say I have **`vertices`** with `label` **`reviewer`** and `property` **`name`**.

I can query for 'John Smith' with:

```
g.V().hasLabel('reviewer').has('name', eq('John Smith'))
```

But I ***cannot*** query for null 'name' with:

```
g.V().hasLabel('reviewer').has('name', eq(null))
```

The above returns empty for me despite having reviewers with `null` name (i.e. **`reviewer`** with property **`name`** not set).

So what's the gremlin query to find vertices with `null` property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm wondering if you might get different behavior on different `Graph` implementations, but on TinkerGraph you can do:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('reviewer').hasNot('name')
==>v[0]
```